# Check xslt code for duplicate varable names and replace them

Tags: xml, transform, xslt-2.0

im using an auto generated code tool to produce xslt code, but i observed an issue. Sometimes the variable names that are declared are the same and this is causing issues in my implementation. Let me give an example. The code that is produced is like this:

```
<xsl:template name="My_Template">
        <xsl:variable name="var7_map_of_House" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:for-each select="$var9_House/Item">
                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var8_count_as_string" as="xs:string" select="xs:string(fn:count($var7_map_of_House))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var5_map_of_HCon" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:for-each select="$var9_House/Item/postcode">
                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var7_map_of_House" as="xs:string" select="xs:string(fn:count($var5_map_of_HCon))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var1_map_of_HouseCon" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:for-each select="$var9_House/Item/name">
                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:template>
```

As you see the variable name "var7_map_of_House" is created twice and this is causing problems. I want to create another xlst or maybe a python script but i believe xslt is better to identify values that are declared twice and replace these values with something unique. For example i have this variable name `variable name="var7_map_of_House"`If i searched the XSLT and found that this value is used twice or more i must replace this value with a unique name for example `"var27_map_of_House"`. Also wherever this duplicate value is used under its declaration i must replace it with the new value. Do you know if this is achievable and how? I'm pretty new to xslt. The code above with this transformation must be:

```
<xsl:template name="My_Template">
        <xsl:variable name="var7_map_of_House" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:for-each select="$var9_House/Item">
                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var8_count_as_string" as="xs:string" select="xs:string(fn:count($var7_map_of_House))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var5_map_of_HCon" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:for-each select="$var9_House/Item/postcode">
                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var27_map_of_House" as="xs:string" select="xs:string(fn:count($var5_map_of_HCon))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var1_map_of_HouseCon" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:for-each select="$var9_House/Item/name">
                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: XSLT can of course process XSLT as its input and also output XSLT as its result. But on an XPath expression level doing variable substitution in attribute expressions you will probably need to use an XPath parser implemented in XSLT, to get that right. The Rex parser generator can generate one, I think, from the XPath grammar.

Comment: Im gonna check it @MartinHonnen. Have you ever used it?

Comment: Maybe would it better to use python then for it?

Comment: are you also sure that i dont need just XSLT?

Comment: I have certainly done XSLT transformations to process and/or output XSLT. I have also used the Rex parser generator occasionally. As for only needing XSLT,  it depends on how well you trust substring/regular expression based variable replacement to do the job.

Comment: How would you do that with an XSLT? Can you give me a brief example to use it and accept it as an answer?

Comment: I have added an answer to give you a rough approach to identify duplicates and rename the variable name in the declaration. To rename variable references in following siblings more work is needed.

Answer (score 0):

On a very rough level, if you expect your relevant `xsl:variable` to be children of e.g. `xsl:template`, to identify the duplicates and change them (below I don't try to rename the second `var7_map_of_House` to what you have shown but to `var7_map_of_House2`, you can use a key e.g.

```
  <xsl:key name="varname" match="xsl:variable" use="@name"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="xsl:template/xsl:variable[not(. is key('varname', @name, ..)[1])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="name" select="concat(@name, index-of(key('varname', @name, ..)/generate-id(), generate-id()))"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @name, node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

But identifying and transforming the following sibling elements to do the variable reference name change is more than trivial, I can't spell that out directly, with the current version (3) of XSLT I wonder whether `xsl:iterate` can help with that and/or would think about using `for-each-group group-starting-with` to identify "groups" of nodes where I need to substitute variables.

Comment: The tricky case is where two variables with the same name have nested scopes. But in the example they don't. It's very unclear whether we are trying to solve the problem for the example given (which is trivial) or for some more general case (which requires complete static analysis of the XSLT code and its XPath expressions), or for something in between.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I agree that in general you would need a static analysis of the XSLT code and its XPath expressions and that nesting complicates things. It doesn't look like an issue solvable on StackOverflow, unless that (probably) tool generated XSLT input has some simple, easy to process, regular structure.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you generating a template rule that declares five variables, and then doesn't use them for anything? It's equivalent to a template rule that does nothing at all.

Changing the names of the variables (`xsl:variable/@name`) is very easy, but changing references to the variables (like `$var7_map_of_House`) is much harder, because presumably you don't know which of the duplicate variables such a reference is supposed to point to. In your example, of course, the duplicate variables are unreferenced, so it hardly matters.

Comment: Lol… I assume he has tried to create a minimal usable example

Comment: How would you do it only for this example? @Michael Kay

Comment: I would probably do it in XSLT 3.0 using xsl:iterate, building a map of variable names (and their replacements); when you encounter a variable whose name is already in the map, replace it with a name that isn't in the map. But as I say, the hard part is replacing references to the variables, not renaming the variables themselves.